# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - Invoking adapter procedure with REST API failing

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to retrieve data from an HTTP adapter using the new REST API.
this is some of my JSON objects returned:

```json
    "items": [
        {
            "category": "category 1",
            "produit": [
                {
                    "id": "57",
                    "name": "this is my name",
                    "answer": [
                        {
                            "id": "146",
                            "answername": " answer 1",
                            "istrue": "0",
                            "questionid": "57"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": "147",
                            "answername": "answer 2",
                            "istrue": "0",
                            "questionid": "57"
                        }
                   ]
               }
          ]
      }
 ]
```

When I invoke the procedure using `WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, options);` it works fine.

```swift
           var invocationData = {
                    adapter : 'AuthentificationAdapter',
                    procedure : 'getquestion',
                    parameters : [jsontab],
                };
            WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
                onSuccess : $.proxy(function(data)
                {
                    deferred.resolve(data.invocationResult.items);
                },this),
                onFailure : $.proxy(function(error)
                {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                },this)
            });
            return deferred.promise
```

But when I used the REST API it returns with `Failed to read the HTTP response` and `Failed to parse JSON string`

here is my resource request code:

```swift
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/AuthentificationAdapter/getquestion", WLResourceRequest.POST, 30000);
            resourceRequest.setQueryParameters(jsontab);
            resourceRequest.send().then(
                $.proxy(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data.responseJSON.items);
                },this),

                $.proxy(function(error) {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                },this)
            );

            return deferred.promise;
```

It seems that the REST API doesn't support complete JSON object as a return like WL.Client do?

Comment: it belongs to the old way RPC . are you sure that REST API support results like JSON tree ?

Answer (score 2):

`WL.Client.invokeProcedure` returns a promise so you should use the following (for the first part) instead of implementing your own.

```
var invocationData = {
         adapter : 'AuthentificationAdapter',
         procedure : 'getquestion',
         parameters : [jsontab],
};

return WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData);
```

`WLResourceRequest.send` also returns a promise so you should use

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("/adapters/AuthentificationAdapter/getquestion", WLResourceRequest.GET, 30000);
resourceRequest.setQueryParameter('params', [jsontab]);
return resourceRequest.send();
```

**Notice** that you have to use `setQueryParameter` and as the first argument you have to pass `'params'` and as the second an array containing all the arguments for the adapter function.

**FYI:** I'm assuming that the previous two snippets of code are inside a function and that's why I'm returning a promise just like you did before.

Comment: that solved the problem ,it was just a syntax error ,Thank you

Comment: Make sure you mark the question as answered if your issue is resolved. thank you

Comment: one last thing ,did ressourceRequest.send() return a promise automatically so i can treat it later when i call the function ?

Comment: Yeah, it returns a promise and you can use the `then`, `fail`, etc just like any other promises

Comment: @Wessim please mark this question. if your issue is resolved